# Simple tensorflow LSTM network get stucks on apple silicon

Tags: python, tensorflow, metal, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am building a very simple LSTM network using the imdb dataset in Tensorflow, in particular running on a Apple Silicon chip (M1 max).

My code is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def get_and_pad_imdb_dataset(num_words=10000, maxlen=None, index_from=2):
    from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb

    # Load the reviews
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path='imdb.npz',
                                                          num_words=num_words,
                                                          skip_top=0,
                                                          maxlen=maxlen,
                                                          start_char=1,
                                                          oov_char=2,
                                                          index_from=index_from)

    x_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train,
                                                        maxlen=None,
                                                        padding='pre',
                                                        truncating='pre',
                                                        value=0)
    
    x_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_test,
                                                           maxlen=None,
                                                           padding='pre',
                                                           truncating='pre',
                                                           value=0)
    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)


def get_imdb_word_index(num_words=10000, index_from=2):
    imdb_word_index = tf.keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index(
                                        path='imdb_word_index.json')
    imdb_word_index = {key: value + index_from for
                       key, value in imdb_word_index.items() if value <= num_words-index_from}
    return imdb_word_index

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = get_and_pad_imdb_dataset(maxlen=25)

imdb_word_index = get_imdb_word_index()

max_index_value = max(imdb_word_index.values())

embedding_dim = 16

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = max_index_value+1, output_dim = embedding_dim, mask_zero = True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 16),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer = 'adam')


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size = 32)
```

The code works absolutely fine on Google Colab and I am quite sure it is correct. However, on my Apple Silicon chip it gets stucked at the very first epoch and it doesn't seem to progress at all.

This is all I get from the log:

```
Epoch 1/3
2022-02-15 22:10:34.093907: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
```

I have already used my Apple Silicon chip with other tensorflow models without any problems at all.

Is there a way to debug/see what is going on with tensorflow on my apple silicon during the fit call? Does anyone know which could be the problem? Does anyone can test this code on another M1 machine if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `tensorflow-macos` to 2.8 and `tensorflow-metal` to 0.4 solved the problem.

It seems that it is a commong bug that affects previous tensorflow versions, in particular when working with text related layers/model. As an example, in my case the problem was the `Embedding` layer.

A similar issue has been opened [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698569), fixed by updating tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

[TensorFlow is not supported by M1 silicon.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44751)

It is possible to get it installed with some features working, but anything that uses any C under the hood won't work. There are some workarounds such as [installing with MiniForge](https://betterprogramming.pub/installing-tensorflow-on-apple-m1-with-new-metal-plugin-6d3cb9cb00ca), but you're always going to have some issues.

Comment: I actually installed Tensorflow following this official guide by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ They managed to make TF run on the M1 GPU

Comment: Yes, that's the same process that the link I posted uses. Still, this is a workaround method by Apple to get TensorFlow to work. TensorFlow does not have native support for M1 architecture and until it does, you're going to have weird bugs.

I'm able to get TF to install and work with some models using the Metal method, but some models just flat out will not work.

Comment: I might open an issue on TF Github repo then, just to report this behaviour